# Конвертировать значения свойств объекта 0 и 1 в тип Boolean

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив объектов:

```
[{
  title: 'name 1',
  isActive: 1,
  isBlocked: 0
}, {
  title: 'name 2',
  isActive: 0,
  isBlocked: 1
},
    ...
}]
```

Как можно конвертировать поля *isActive* и *isBlocked* в тип *Boolean*, чтобы было `true` или `false`. На выходе должен получиться новый массив объектов следующего вида:

```
[{
  title: 'name 1',
  isActive: true,
  isBlocked: false
}, {
  title: 'name 2',
  isActive: false,
  isBlocked: true
},
    ...
}]
```

Comment: `isActive = isActive == true` `isActive = !!isActive`

Comment: isActive = Boolean(isActive)

Comment: Рустам Гимранов да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так можно

```js
let arr = [{
title: 'name 1',
isActive: 1,
isBlocked: 0
},
{
title: 'name 2',
isActive: 0,
isBlocked: 1
}]

const newArr =  arr.map(item=>{
  const newItem = {...item};
  newItem.isActive = Boolean(item.isActive);
  newItem.isBlocked = Boolean(item.isBlocked);
  return newItem;
})
console.log(newArr);
```

Здесь мы создаем новый массив а не меняем исходный, 
что позволит избежать сайдэффектов и тд, и тп.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать написать что-то вроде универсальной функции.

```js
var arr = [{
    title: 'name 1',
    isActive: 1,
    isBlocked: 0
  },
  {
    title: 'name 2',
    isActive: 0,
    isBlocked: 1
  },
]

function convertToBoolean(arr, keys) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) || !Array.isArray(keys)) {
    return arr.slice();
  }
  return arr.map(m => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
      if (typeof m === 'object' && m.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        m[key] = !!m[key];
      }
    });
    return m;
  });
}


console.log(convertToBoolean(arr, ['isActive', 'isBlocked']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Это дело можно организовать перебором, чтобы независимо от конктерных ключей.

```js
var arr = [
  { title: 'name 1', isActive: 1, isBlocked: 0},
  { title: 'name 2', isActive: 0, isBlocked: 1},
]

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
  for( var u in arr[i] ){
    if( arr[i][u] === 0 || arr[i][u] === 1 ){
      arr[i][u] = !!arr[i][u];
    }
  }
}

console.log( arr );
```

Comment: и  потом у тебя поле с числовые значения тоже в булевы   преобразуются... не сильно то универсально